# How can I use a method I created in another class with Scanner class to provide data to that method?

Tags: java

I am trying to have the user enter base and height of a triangle and with them  calculate the hypotenuse.

The error I get is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError` and points to the line 42 where I ask the user.

Heres the actual code:

```
public class RTTriangle {
     private double base;        // properties
     private double height;
     private double hypotenuse;

public RTTriangle()         // Constructors
{
    base = 2;
    height = 0;
}
public RTTriangle(double BASE2, double HEIGHT2)         // Constructors
{
    base = BASE2;
    height = HEIGHT2;
}

public void setBase(double BasE)       // setters
{
    base =  BasE;
}

public void setHeight(double Height)
{
    height = Height;
}

public double getBase()           // getters
{
    return base;
}

public double getHeight()
{
    return height;
}

public double getHypotenuse(double x, double y)
{
    hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(base, 2.0) + Math.pow(height, 2.0));
    return hypotenuse = getHypotenuse(base, height);
}

public double getArea()
{
    double area;
    area = base * height;
    return area;
}

public double getPerimeter()
{
    double Perimeter;
    Perimeter = height + base + this.getHypotenuse();
    return Perimeter;
}

}
```

I have tried to mess around with it and but i still cant seem to work. 
and this is how im calling it onto my other class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RTTriangleDemo {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    double base;
    double height;

    Scanner SCAN = new Scanner(System.in);
    RTTriangle TRI1 = new RTTriangle();
    RTTriangle TRI2 = new RTTriangle();

    System.out.print("Enter the base of the Triangle: " );
    base = SCAN.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter the length of the Triangle: " );
    height = SCAN.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("The hypotenuse is: " + TRI1.getHypotenuse(base, height));
```

If anyone can help me with this I'll be very grateful.

Comment: What is the error you get? Could you copy the stack trace?

Comment: A stack overflow error means you have an infinite recursion.  On what specific line do you get this error?  What does that line do?  (Hint: Why does your `getHypotenuse()` method call `getHypotenuse()`?)

Comment: return hypotenuse = getHypotenuse(base, height); is the problem you should just return hypotenuse

Answer (score 2):

In the following method:

```
public double getHypotenuse(double x, double y)
{
    hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(base, 2.0) + Math.pow(height, 2.0));
    return hypotenuse = getHypotenuse(base, height);
}
```

change the last line to just

```
return hypotenuse;
```

The rest is a recursive call, which you don't need. It will just keep calling itself infinitely until you run out of space on the stack, crashing your program.

---

Not related to your problem, but you have a constructor that takes the base and height of a triangle. I'd consider using that, so you don't have to pass those values to the `hypotenuse` method.

Comment: OHHHH, THANK YOU!! that fixed it, thank you very much. and i will look into that!

Answer (score 0):

The getHypotenuse method is recursive:

```
double getHypotenuse(double x, double y) {
    hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(base, 2.0) + Math.pow(height,2.0));
    return hypotenuse = getHypotenuse(base, height); // <-- recursion
}
```

Moreover, it is infinitely recursive. Instead, it should be:

```
double getHypotenuse(double x, double y) {
    hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(base, 2.0) + Math.pow(height,2.0));
    return hypotenuse;
}
```

Comment: THAANK YOU VERY MUCH! I dont know what recursive means but ill look into it more. Thank you very much